# Why AutoCAD cannot open dwf files, directly?

Tags: autocad

I use AutoCAD 2015. When try to open **dwf** files with AutoCAD get error that

> Can not find the specified drawing file.
> Please verify that the file
> exists.

I search in web and found this solution :
I open in AutoCAD empty project and type in command **dwfattach** and press enter. One windows opened then I select my file and click ok.

In main windows request position that I set all to 0.
I open layout windows and **dwf** file displayed.

I must do all this steps for all files.

I need a solution that open **dwf** files directly!

Answer (score 0):

According to AutoDesk you cannot open a DWF file.  Their website says:

> AutoCAD, DWG TrueView, and Design Review do not have a conversion
> feature to change DWF files into DWG format. DWF/DWFx files are a
> "digital plot" file containing only low-intelligence entities. It is
> not intended for use as a drawing file exchange format and cannot be
> fully recovered or changed back to a standard drawing file.

AutoDesk has a process to convert a DWF file into a DWG file in this article:

[How to convert DWF files to DWG format](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/how-to-convert-dwf-files-to-dwg-format.html)